# Uniformly distributed indices

Tags: probability

I'm stuck on this problem:

Let $U$, $V$ and $W$ be independent random variables with uniform distribution on $[0, 1]$. Find the distribution of $(UV)^W$.

The only thing I could think to try was to take logs but that seemed to be a dead end. If anyone could give me some pointers, that would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MathSE!  Here's a [handy guide](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for how to mark up math nicely on this site.

Comment: You can use the change of variables formula. There's not much else you can do.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach seems to work:
$$\ln Z = W(\ln U + \ln V)$$
By variable transformation, the pdf is found easily:
$$Q = \ln U \rightarrow f_q(q) = e^{q} {\rm\ for\ }-\infty<q<0 $$
By convolution:
$$R = \ln U + \ln V \rightarrow f_r(r) = \int_r^0 e^q\,e^{r-q}\, dq=-r\,e^r {\rm\ for\ } -\infty<r<0 $$
Just continue with another "convolution" this time Mellin, and then transform the RV $\ln Z$ back to $Z$. Expression comes out in terms of an incomplete gamma function.